# Node.js Python-shell: while true loop not working

Tags: python, node.js

I've this simple `Python` script print out a message every second:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

while True:
    print u"Message"
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'm trying to integrate a 3rd party Python script with the above structure with `Node.js` using [`python-shell`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell).

I'm having this JS script to get all messages from the Python script:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var options = {
  scriptPath: './'
};

var pyshell = new PythonShell('test.py',options);

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
  // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement) 
  console.log(message);
});

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit 
pyshell.end(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

But it seems, that the `while True` in Python cause that the on-event is not called. How can I solve this? Can I change the loop inside the `Python` script to something compatible with `python-shell`?

Comment: `the while True in Python cause that the on-event is not called` - True. Its an infinite loop. `How can I solve this?` - Remove the infinite loop.

Comment: My 3rd party python script is designed to run in an infinite loop checking state of some device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to flush `sys.stdout` as the output is buffered because it is piped:

```
import time
import sys
while True:
    print u"Message"
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

You will receive the output immediately once flushed:

```
$ nodejs n.js
Message
Message
Message
.....
```

You may be able to set the buffering to line buffered or unbuffered when you start the shell but I am  not overly familiar with nodejs.

There is actually a way to set the `-u` flag to get unbuffered output with the `pythonOptions` flag:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var pyshell = new PythonShell('test.py',{scriptPath:"./", pythonOptions: ['-u']});

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
  // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement) 
  console.log(message);

});

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit 
pyshell.end(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

The output will be unbuffered so there will be no need to flush stdout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works great! But how can I exit the infinite loop with nodejs?